# Finding all successors of a node in a DAG that are of given type and have a route to the origin node not containing a node of the same type

Tags: python, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a sequential series of tasks (nodes) in a directed acyclic graph, where some tasks are done manually and other tasks are done automatically. If a given manual task is updated, I need to identify all downstream manual tasks for which there exists at least one route between the updated task and the downstream manual task that does not have another manual task on it. Moreover, for each of these downstream manual tasks, I need to identify all other manual tasks that lie on any route between them and the updated task.

For example, consider the following set of graph edges, where only task D is done automatically.

```
[A, B]
[B, C]
[A, D]
[D, E]
[C, E]
```

If task A is updated, then I would like to send a notification to the owners of tasks B and E. Task B is only dependent on A, so work on it can start immediately and finish at any time. Likewise, there is a route A -> D -> E, where D is updated automatically as soon as A changes, so one of the revised inputs to task E is ready, and task E should be notified of this. However, for task E, while work can start right away, it cannot finish until C is completed, and C depends in turn on B. So while I would like to notify the owner of task E that A has changed, I also need to notify them that work cannot complete until both B and C are updated. Finally, the owner of task C should not receive a notification, because they are solely dependent on task B, and task B has not yet been updated. As soon as task B is completed then the owner of task C receives a notification, but no message is sent to E, since C has not yet been updated, and B only affects E via C. Finally, when C is updated than E gets another notification alerting them that C has been updated.

I am using the Python `networkx` library to encode the graph, so any solution leveraging it would be most helpful, though a solution using another library/language could also be enough if I can figure out how to translate it back to the `networkx` case.

### EDIT

Adding solution to full problem based on @Xavi's comments. Also added a new manual task F that we want to ignore because while it is a predecessor of E it is not a descendant of A so it doesn't need to be updated.

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

G = nx.DiGraph()
manual_tasks = set(['A','B','C','E','F'])
G.add_edges_from([
    ["A","B"],
    ["B","C"],
    ["C","E"],
    ["A","D"],
    ["D","E"],
    ["F","D"]
])
task_updated = "A"
downstream_next = [] # Next set of manual tasks to notify
downstream_all = set(nx.dfs_predecessors(G, task_updated).keys())
upstream = defaultdict(list) # Among notified tasks, manual predecessors that are pending

def explore_down(node):
    for child in G.successors(node):
        if child in manual_tasks: downstream_next.append(child)
        else: explore_down(child)

def explore_up(origin, node):
    for parent in G.predecessors(node):
        if parent in downstream_all:
            if parent in manual_tasks:
                upstream[origin].append(parent)
            explore_up(origin, parent)

explore_down(task_updated)
for node in downstream_next:
    explore_up(node, node)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers is only regarding the first part of the problem (identifying manual tasks that are downstream a route of automatic tasks from the original manual task). This can be solved modifying any kind of graph exploration. In general:

- Start at the origin manual task, push all its successors to the exploration queue.
- When popping an automatic task from the exploration queue, proceed normally (i.e. push its successors to the exploration queue, update predecessor map, etc)
- When popping a manual task from the exploration queue, do *not* push anything else to the queue, and mark this task as one of the tasks you're looking for (if necessary, use the predecessor map to recover a path of automatic tasks back to the original task)

The idea is pretty transparent - essentially you just work in the subgraph induced by the automatic tasks, and see if this connects the original manual task to any other manual task.